# CSV response from get request in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am sending an http Get request to elastic search server and i want the response to be in csv format.Like in solr we can specify wt=csv is there any way In elastic Search too ?
My query is :

```
enter code here
 http://elasticServer/_search?q=RCE:"some date" OR 
 VENDOR_NAME:"Anuj"&from=0&size=5&sort=@timestamp


  -----After that i want to force the server to return me response in csv format
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, ES supports only two data formats: JSON and YAML. However, if you're open to using Logstash, you can achieve what you want very easily like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    query => 'RCE:"some date" OR VENDOR_NAME:"Anuj"'
    size => 5
  }
}
filter {}
output {
  csv {
    fields => ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
    path => "/path/to/data.csv"
  }
}
```

Since the `elasticsearch` input uses scrolling, you cannot specify any sorting. So if sorting is really important to you, you can use the [`http_poller` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html) instead of the `elasticsearch` one, like this:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      es => {
        method => get
        url => 'http://elasticServer/_search?q=RCE:"some date" OR VENDOR_NAME:"Anuj"&from=0&size=5&sort=@timestamp'
        headers => {
          Accept => "application/json"
        }
      }
    }
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {}
output {
  csv {
    fields => ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
    path => "/path/to/data.csv"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply Is there any support for Logstash in java ?
 How can i use Logstash to query using java and UI

Comment: Logstash is an ETL tool. You configure it like I showed above and then you run it. You can't call it via Java. You can try what @volatilevar suggested in his answer, that might work from Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ElasticSearch plugin on Github called [Elasticsearch Data Format Plugin](https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-dataformat) that should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: can we use that in java

Comment: Short answer is yes, because it is not language dependent. This is a plugin for ElasticSearch. You just install it ( as in here https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-dataformat#for-5x) and can use any Java HTTP client to make HTTP GET requests to get the csv format data back.

Comment: As we are not using elastic server locally we have deployed it some where do we need to install that plugin there or do we need to install in the system.
As i m running an window environment. Thanks for further help. please respond back

Comment: Sure -- You will need to install the plugin on the system where you installed ElasticSearch

Comment: Thank you so much @volatilevar

Comment: I want to search for some name on my server how i can write a get request.Its not working
"server/term/_data?format=csv&source="NAME":anuj"